# How to send message on event from pc bot is running on? Not from message/channel?

Tags: discord.py

have watchdog file observer. When specific file appears I obtain it and I want to send it into a discord channel.

What commands/events should I look at/use to do this? It's not coming from async discord function. Event is not coming from channel or message, but from obtaining of the file from the PC which bot is runnin on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the question well, though, if you want to do something when the bot comes online my suggestion is: use the on_ready event. Here is an example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Hello!'))
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(client.user.id))
```